# Removing Action Bar (Android Studios)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

Newer templates provided by android studio make use of `themes.xml` instead of `styles.xml` and changing `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"` to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` dosen't remove the action bar.
do you know how can I remove the action bar in the XML files?
==> also I tried your suggestions of changing `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"` to `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"` in both `theme.xml` files and this is the outcome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/heimI.png
as you can see in the image action bar is only getting bigger. is it bugged? what do you think?
My XML Files:
values\themes.xml:

```
 <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="Theme.Idcard" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_500</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->y
            <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
            <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        </style>
    </resources>
```

night\themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Idcard" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

and here is a link to the app files on Github: [code files](https://github.com/itzMehrshad/NoActionBarProblem)

Comment: technically there is no difference between `themes.xml` & `styles.xml` in terms of the naming

Comment: @Zain why do you think it doesn't work though?

Comment: Probably you *setSupportActionBar()* by mistake

Comment: oh, in the XML files? sorry for asking too many questions I'm just newbie in android

Comment: No in activity/fragment (java or kotlin) files.. feel free to share it

Comment: its just a default activity i guess: `package com.example.idcard;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}`

Comment: Right it's the default. But still this can't make the issue reproduced, if you can share the project as a skeleton (not the entire one) on Github, so we can deeply investigate it.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, ill do it right away!

Comment: @Zain here is the [link](https://github.com/itzMehrshad/NoActionBarProblem), I've just uploaded the app code files, and again, thank you for your time <3

Comment: I just added `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` in the `\res\values\themes` and it solved the problem for me .. please check [here](https://imgur.com/a/HFjHDVN)

Comment: yea, I think it's a bug, I'll re-install android studios.

Comment: Did you see it when you run it on emulator or physical device?

Comment: @Zain on both emulator and actual device, but it got fixed right after re-installing android studio! definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything I finally **re-installed Android Studios** and it fixed right away! it obviously was a bug.
So if ever you got into problems like that, witch things don't work as they should, re-installing Android Studios is always an option.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"` instead of `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

```
<style name="Theme.Pine" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/qGreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/qGreen</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: I tried it but it makes the action bar two times bigger. it doesn't remove the action bar.

Comment: @Mehrshad you need to add in both themes.xml and themes.xml(night). i have updated the code please check

Comment: thank you for your time, I did as you suggest. I've edited my question and as you can see in the image it doesn't fix the problem. does it work for you yourself? maybe my android studio is bugged or smth.

Comment: @Mehrshad Please share your xml file

Comment: I edited the post and I've added both XML Codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

`<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`

You simply keep the `DayNight` but change `DarkActionBar` to `NoActionBar` at the end for both XML files. (`themes.xml` and `themes.xml(night)`)

Thus it should look like this in both folder:

```
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: thank you for your time, I did as you suggest. I've edited my question and as you can see in the image it doesn't fix the problem. does it work for you yourself? maybe my android studio is bugged or smth.

Comment: It's a bug. Sorry for the late respond. If you reinstalled the program, let me know. My solution is the exact answer to your question if you have no issues.

Comment: Np man. it was a bug and got fixed right after I re-installed the android studios. tnx again<3